# Template metaprogramming, conflicts in cv-qualification error

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to implement a sine function using template metaprogramming. However I get the error 'radtest' is not a valid template argument for  double & because of conflicts in cv-qualification. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <double&, int, int> struct 
Series;

template <double& rad> struct Sine
{
    enum
    {
        maxterms=10 
    };      

    static inline double sin()
    {
        return (rad) * 
  Series<(rad), 0, maxterms>::val(); 
    }
};

template <double& rad, int i, int 
maxterms> struct Series
{
   enum 
   {
         cont = i+1 != maxterms, 
         nxt1 = (i+1)*cont,
         nxtmax = maxterms*cont      
   };

   // uses recursive definition of 
   // Sine
   // sin(x)=x*term(0)
   // term(n)=1-
   // x*x/(2*n+2)/(2*n+3)*term(n+1)
   static inline double val()
   {
       return 1 - (rad)*
(rad)/(2.0*i+2.0)/(2.0*i+3.0)
      * Series<rad * cont, nxt1, 
nxtmax>::val(); 

   }
};

#define SineT(rad) Sine<rad>::sin()
constexpr double radtest=0.707;

int main() 
{
    cout << "Sine of " << radtest 
<< " is: " << SineT(radtest);
    return 0;
}
```

What could be the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think it will work with this: `double& rad` as a template argument

Comment: `rad * cont` in your `Series<rad * cont, nxt1, 
nxtmax>::val()` is not `constexpr double &`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `radtest` is `const` (implied by `constexpr`) so you cannot have `double&` parameter of `sine` bind to it.

If you try and make it `double radtest` (not constexpr) or if you try and make all template parameters `const double&` then you get into another problem: you cannot bind a temporary to a reference non-type template parameter. This is explicitly disallowed by the standard:

> § 14.3.2 Template non-type arguments
>
> A *template-argument* for a non-type *template-parameter* shall be
>   a converted constant expression (5.20) of the type of the
>   template-parameter. For a non-type *template-parameter* of reference
>   or pointer type, the value of the constant expression shall not refer
>   to (or for a pointer type, shall not be the address of):
>
> - ...
> - (1.2) a temporary object (12.2),
> - ...

I personally don't see a way out of this mess. This (using references as template non-type parameters) is really pushing the boundaries of what the C++ template system can do.

What I can recommend is to just create a `constexpr` sin function.

Comment: Yes this is exactly the problem I had while trying to make all the parameters const double&. I have tried using structs as parameters but have encountered other compilation problems.